# About $E^\infty$ spectral sequence.

Tags: homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

While learning spectral sequence, I have trouble realizing where the terms $E^k$ get stationary
$E^\infty$.
For bounded chain complexes, it happens since the filtration is finite. But, for example, the Basic pathspace fibration in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre_spectral_sequence#Example_computations) page states that $E^2=E^\infty$ and atually use the $d_{n+1}$ in page $E^{n+1}$. I have not came across the proof of Larey-Serre sequence though. I wonder if it's related to a filtration.

Would you please explain why there is $E^2=E^\infty$ in this example?

Comment: If there is a nontrivial differential then $E^2 \not\cong E^\infty$.  Maybe there's a typo?

Comment: @JHF I'm considering a concrete example in that wiki page. I want to know why  $E^2=E^\infty$ holds.

Comment: Which example are you looking at?  Nowhere in the "Basic pathspace fibration" example is it claimed that $E^2 = E^\infty$.

Comment: @JHF "3.3 Basic pathspace fibration" $\Omega \mathbb{S}^n \to P\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$

Comment: Nowhere in the "Basic pathspace fibration" example is it claimed that $E^2 = E^\infty$.  And the Serre spectral sequence for $\Omega S^n \to PS^n \to S^n$ does *not* degenerate.

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood the meaning. I'll be grateful if you can explain it clearer as an   answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Serre spectral sequence for $\Omega S^n \to PS^n \to S^n$ does not degenerate, i.e., $E^2 \neq E^\infty$.  If it did, the projection $PS^n \to S^n$ would induce a surjective in homology which is absurd since $PS^n$ is contractible but $S^n$ has nontrivial homology in degree $n$.

Indeed, as Wikipedia explains, there is a $d^n$-differential that kills the class in $H_n(S^n)$.  After that, there are no more possible nontrivial differentials, so the spectral sequence collapses and $E^{n+1} = E^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. In fact, I forgot the point that the path space $PS^n$ is contractible.